# Bi-directional ListView with React Native

Tags: react-native

Right now, React Native ListView supports loading more data only in one direction, towards the end. If I add data towards the beginning, then it'll jump the scroll position.

Also, the ListView calls onEndReached in only in one direction.

Is there any way to implement a bi-directional ListView so that I can load more items in either direction without jumping the scroll position?

This is useful in case like, say the user came from a notification to an old item. So it'll be ideal to take the user to that part. Then as the user can scroll in either direction, I'll need to load data in either direction, without affecting scroll position.

Comment: Wanna know too -- did you solve that?

Comment: Nope. But the approach has to be something like - keep track of current scroll position, prepend new items and measure the height difference, then adjust the scroll position.